# Javascript: Multidimensional array sort by specified index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

If I have an array that looks like the following:

var array[0] = [$name, $date, $bTrue];
...
...
...

How would I sort that array by one of the 1st dimensional array values?  Thanx in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort 2 dimensional array by column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/how-to-sort-2-dimensional-array-by-column-value)

Comment: Peter answered my question 12 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a simple sort callback

```
var arr = [[1,5,2],[1,8,2],[1,2,2]];

console.log( arr );

arr.sort( function( a, b )
{
  // Sort by the 2nd value in each array
  if ( a[1] == b[1] ) return 0;
  return a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : 1;
});

console.log( arr );
```

the `Array.sort()` method takes a callback into which two elements are passed.  It's a basic bubble sort

- If `a` is to be sorted ahead of `b`, return -1 (or any negative value)
- If `b` is to be sorted ahead of `a`, return 1 (or any positive value)
- If `a` and `b` are equal, return 0;

Comment: Thanks Peter, I appreciate the quick response.