# Some (JavaScript) eventd reorder a ordered html selection options

Tags: javascript, html

I have an unordered (dynamic generated via jsp `<c:out>`-tags) list of options in a `<select>`-tag.
After the tag has been rendered, I reorder it with a simple JavaScript function.

If I use the `onClick`- event handler of the `<select>`-element, I'll get / see the ordered list on the webpage. If I append the function to my `onLoaded`-event handler, the function will be called and the debugger shows me the correct values, but the resulting order of my `option`-elements is not sorted.

If i add the method call after the dom-element with a plain `<script>`-tag, the same behavior happens.

**Limitations**

- No jQuery
- Data source is not sortable
- `onClick`-handler is not a prober solution
- Has to work in old browsers

**JavaScript Source**

```
  function sortSelectById(elementId) {
    var list = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var options = []

    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      options[i] = [];
      options[i][0] = list.options[i].text;
      options[i][1] = list.options[i].value;
      options[i][2] = list.options[i].selected;
    }

    options.sort();

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      list.options[i].text = options[i][0];
      list.options[i].value = options[i][1];
      list.options[i].selected = options[i][2];
    }

    return;
  }
```

Comment: What JavaScript populates the select list in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you're experiencing is due to the two-dimensional array.  JavaScript needs to be told exactly what to sort by.

We do this by passing in a `compareFunction` to [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Here's an example:

```js
function compareFunction(a, b) {
    if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

function sortSelectById(elementId) {
    var list = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var options = []

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        options[i] = [];
        options[i][0] = list.options[i].text;
        options[i][1] = list.options[i].value;
        options[i][2] = list.options[i].selected;
    }

    options.sort(compareFunction);

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        list.options[i].text = options[i][0];
        list.options[i].value = options[i][1];
        list.options[i].selected = options[i][2];
    }
    document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex = 0;
    return;
}

sortSelectById("select");
```

```html
<select id="select">
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Grape</option>
</select>
```

*The compareFunction was borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/how-to-sort-2-dimensional-array-by-column-value#answer-16097058)*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
The 'issue' was quite simpel but a combination of diffrent mistakes.

1. Do not attach events to `body`, attach it to the root `window` element
2. IE (> 6) requires another method call to append events to a handler
3. IE (> 6) requires a method reference and no direct methodcall with parameters

**The following code works in my scenario**

```
 /* Required by the compatibility requirement for IE8 and older */
 function sortStatus() {
  sortSelectById('elem_id') ;
  // sort other fields...
 }

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', sortStatus, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onload', sortStatus);
}
```

**Update**

Thanks to @Howard Renollet! The tip with the extra comperator is quite neat and works perfectly!

Comment: Sorry - I'm not so familiar with Stackoverflow. Have a nice day. :)