# Javascript sort by element inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an complex array order by one column of the array.

For example, this array might looks like

`array = [["Banana","Chapter3"], ["Orange","Chapter2"], ["Apple","Chapter1"]];`

I want it to sort by `Chapter`, so the result will be

```
array = ["Apple","Chapter1"],["Orange","Chapter2"],["Banana","Chapter3"]]
```

But if I do `array.sort`, it will become

```
[["Apple","Chapter1"],["Banana","Chapter3"],["Orange","Chapter2"]]
```

It seems sort by first element's ascii code. How do I sort by specific element in array?

I also created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4f63c6w/) to illustrate my idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/how-to-sort-2-dimensional-array-by-column-value . Top answer has a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a comparator to `sort`:

```
var array = [["Banana","Chapter3"], ["Orange","Chapter2"], ["Apple","Chapter1"]];

var sorted = array.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a[1] > b[1]) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a[1] < b[1]) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});

console.log(sorted);

// [ [ 'Apple', 'Chapter1' ],
//   [ 'Orange', 'Chapter2' ],
//   [ 'Banana', 'Chapter3' ] ]
```