# Sorting multidimensional js array

Tags: javascript

SUGGESTED DUPLICATE ANSWER DOES NOT SOLVE

I have 4 hidden inputs where the value increments based on user actions. Var Id gets the id of each input value and var val its value.

```
<input class="howmanyproducts" id="<?php echo $value; ?>" name="<?php echo $value; ?>" type="hidden" value="0">
```

I push each set of values into an array which will output:

```
8(id), 1(val) 
9, 2 
3, 5 
7, 8
```

I need to sort these values based on the val. So the above should return:

```
7, 8
3, 5
9, 2
8, 1
```

Below is what I have so far, hope the question makes sense!

```
$("#proddiv .howmanyproducts").each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var val = $(this).val();
    ids.push([id, +val]);
 });

    ids.sort(function(b, a) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
    $("#productorder").val(ids);
    $("#productscore").submit();
```

Below is how I retrieve the form data which needs to be in sorted

```
 $prodorder = $_POST['productorder'];
 $array2 = array_unique(explode(',', $prodorder));
```

My current code is not changing the order at all!

Comment: There is no question in what you posted.

Comment: Your current code looks fine, what's the problem?

Comment: sorry, updated.

Comment: um,  so  how is ids used in submit. You are storing them in a variable... The variable has nothing to do with form values.

Comment: So, it seems like, you are sorting the ids but when you use jquery submit function, it submits the data from the DOM element. So the sorting doesn't affect that actual element.

Comment: Side note - use objects here instead of multi-demensional array. `ids.push({id: id, val: val});`

Comment: I used ids to append to a hidden form item which is submitted (but in the order I want).

Comment: That maybe right Jangmi, how could I amend this so it re-arranges the vaues so I can then append this to an input to be submitted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort 2 dimensional array by column value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/how-to-sort-2-dimensional-array-by-column-value)

Comment: I'd like to see more code if you can provide more : )

Comment: I have added a few more lines :)

Comment: please also post the HTML for `#productorder` and `#productscore`

Comment: Just quick question, are you setting the ids which is array to the value of hidden input?

Comment: Yes Jagmi, but even alerting the ids.sort before this doesnt show the correct outcome

Comment: you have $prodorder and productorder. Do you sure their name are true?

Comment: yes Farzin, they are correct

Comment: So when you log the ids even before sorting, doesn't show the correct outcome? What does it show? Please provide, before sorting, ids and after sorting.

Comment: Your question was about sorting. we mentioned your problem, and now we have another question, and our answer get useless. And i forced to delete a part of my answer. It was better to create a new question.

Comment: I built the html and javascript file based on your file and  it sorts correctly. I think it's a problem with setting the array as a value of DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

item, then form will submit. I think this is your problem, I tested you sort function and it is true:

```
 var arr = [];
    arr.push([1, 3]);
    arr.push([2, 2]);
    arr.push([4, 8]);
    arr.push([0, 9]);
    arr.sort(function (b, a) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I need to use the each function as the ids are dynamic

Comment: you don't need to sort within it though.

Comment: So you must change you code. Submit must go after each ended.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to sort an array of objects with `id` and `val` properties by descending order of the `val` values, is that correct? If that's the case then [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) will do what you need:

```
let A = [{id: 8, val: 1}, {id: 9, val: 2}, {id: 3, val: 5}, {id: 7, val: 8}]
A.sort((a, b) => a.val < b.val)
[{id: 7, val: 8}, {id: 3, val: 5}, {id: 9, val: 2}, {id: 8, val: 1}]
```