# Sort two dimensional array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to sort a two dimensional array using javascript.

**My array :**

```
[
  ['1','6'],
  ['1','5'],
  ['2','3'],
  ['0','4'],
]
```

**My sorting function :**

```
// 1st sort
myArray.sort( function(a, b) {
  return a[0] - b[0];
});

// 2nd sort
myArray.sort( function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1];
});
```

**The result :**

```
["2", "3"]
["0", "4"]
["1", "6"]
["1", "5"]
```

**The result should be :**

```
["0", "4"]
["1", "5"] // 5 before 6 and the left column is sorted
["1", "6"]
["2", "3"]
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/how-to-sort-2-dimensional-array-by-column-value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your **second sort is overriding the sorting done by first sort** and it is only keeping the second column sorted.

You don't need two `sort` functions, just include both in a single sort as:

```
myArray.sort((a, b) => (a[0] - b[0]) || (a[1] - b[1]));
```

or without braces

```
myArray.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]);
```

**Demo**

```js
var myArray = [
    ['1','6'],
    ['1','5'],
    ['2','3'],
    ['12','13'],
    ['0','4'],
];
myArray.sort((a, b) => (a[0] - b[0]) || (a[1] - b[1]));

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: @NinaScholz Sure, I added braces initially for better readability

Comment: @NinaScholz the precedence between `-` and `||` isn't obvious (although it is documented), so braces can help

Comment: oh no. please do not use unary plusses for changing values to number because they are converted to number by using minus operator by default.

Comment: @NinaScholz You are right, I tested without unary plus and it worked as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a different approach for an arbitrary length of the arrays.

This solution assumes, that all inner arrays have the same length.

```js
var array = [['1','6', '1'], ['1','5', '1'], ['1','5', '2'], ['2','3', '0'], ['0','4', '0']];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var d;
    a.some((v, i) => d = v - b[i]);
    return d;
});

console.log(array.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

Comment: `var i = 0, res; while(!(res = a[i] - b[i++])); return res;` ... i still prefer imperative programming...

Comment: @JonasW., right, another possibility, but no length check. it loops forever with equal arrays, value wise.

Answer (score 4):

```
 myArray.sort((a, b) => (a[0] - b[0]) || (a[1] - b[1]));
```

Just sort after the second slot if the first ones are equal