# Sort 2 array by column, as a parameter in a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-3

I can sort an array by column with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/how-to-sort-2-dimensional-array-by-column-value) It looks a bit like this:

var myArr = [
[0, 10,  20, "jam"],
[1, 20,  14, "carrots"],
[2, 30,  14, "custard"],
[3, 40,  16, "beef"],
[4, 0 ,  16, "gwen"],
]

```
myArr.sort(sort_2d_array);

function sort_2d_array(arr) 
{

  var column = 1;

  if (a[column] === b[column]) 
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    return (a[column] < b[column]) ? -1 : 1;
  }
}
```

Which gets sorted as:
4, 0 ,  16, "gwen"
0, 10,  20, "jam"
1, 20,  14, "carrots"
2, 30,  14, "custard"
3, 40,  16, "beef"

However, since it's written as a function expression, how do I write it if I wanted to pass column as a parameter into the function? Without having 4 versions of the same function with a different value vorm `column`.

Personally, I'd find it easier to comprehend and understand in the traditional form:

```
function sort_2d_array_by_column(arr, column)
```

Or is that putting the cart before the horse?

If this doesn't make sense, I'll have another go at writing it. #spectrumofconfusion

Comment: Please show an example input and output, sorted in the way you want.

Comment: Where do you call `sort_2d_array_by_column` and where is `sort_2d_array` defined?

Comment: Also, are you sure the ES3 tag is correct?

Comment: do you really need a solution for **ecmascript-3**?

Comment: @NinaScholz 'fraid so! Adobe has yet to update Photoshop script from version 3. this needs to run without fancy things like map and filter and all the other good stuff ;)

Comment: @vlaz - sorry, my bad missed that in getting myself confused. Have now updated code

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over the index and return the sorting function as callback.

```js
var sortByIndex = function (index) {
        return function (a, b) {
            return (a[index] > b[index]) - (a[index] < b[index]);
        };
    },
    array = [[0, 10, 20, "jam"], [1, 20, 14, "carrots"], [2, 30, 14, "custard"], [3, 40, 16, "beef"], [4, 0, 16, "gwen"]];

array.sort(sortByIndex(1));
console.log(array);

array.sort(sortByIndex(3));
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is tagged ES3. I'm not totally sure if OP meant it but still.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have some functional programming here:

```js
const cmp = (a, b) => (a > b) - (a < b)
const column = p => o => o[p]
const by = f => (x, y) => cmp(f(x), f(y))


myArr = [
    [0, 10, 20, "jam"],
    [1, 20, 14, "carrots"],
    [2, 30, 14, "custard"],
    [3, 40, 16, "beef"],
    [4, 0, 16, "gwen"],
]

myArr.sort(by(column(2)));
console.log(myArr.map(JSON.stringify))


myArr.sort(by(column(3)));
console.log(myArr.map(JSON.stringify))
```

A less "advanced", but perhaps more readable (and ES3 compatible) version:

```
function sortByColumn(arr, col) {
    return arr.sort(function(x, y) {
        x = x[col]
        y = y[col]
        return (x > y) ? 1 : (x < y ? -1 : 0)
    })
}
```