# sort array based on other array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have 2 lists/arrays:

[Examples]:

```
let labels = ["John", "Sophie", "Hannah", "Emilia"]

let data = [10, 40, 24, 25]
```

I want to sort both arrays with the order of data. (Each name corresponds with the value in the other array at the same index). I would use an object like this {name: value} but for my needs, they have to be seperate (at least the result). I have found a solution but i find it isnt very elegant.

[Desired Output Example]:

```
let data = [40, 25, 24, 10]

let labels = ["Sophie", "Emilia", "Hannah", "John"]
```

basically the other array has to be sorted with the same pattern that the data array will be sorted (numbers ascending)

Comment: Shouldn't these two arrays be one array, which you can sort more easily?

Comment: Are there duplicate values?

Comment: Well show your solution then. Maybe someone will find a way to improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this elegantly with the `zip` function (see also [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)). `zip` has an interesting property of being its own inverse, that is `zip(zip([a, b])) === [a, b]`, so we zip both arrays into one, sort it and zip again.

```js
let zip = (...a) => a[0].map((_, n) => a.map(b => b[n]))


let labels = ["John", "Sophie", "Hannah", "Emilia"]

let data = [10, 40, 24, 25];


[labels, data] = zip(...
    zip(labels, data)
        .sort((x, y) => y[1] - x[1])
)


console.log(...labels)
console.log(...data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take some abstract functions, inspired by

- [How can I perform operations in JavaScript just like we do pipeline of operations in Java streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568053/how-can-i-perform-operations-in-javascript-just-like-we-do-pipeline-of-operation/54568750#54568750)
  and
- [Sort 2 array by column, as a parameter in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67568181/sort-2-array-by-column-as-a-parameter-in-a-function/67568303#67568303)

and transpose the data, sort it descending by index 1 and transpose the result. Then reassign by destructuring.

```js
const
    swap = fn => (a, b) => fn(b, a),
    prop = k => o => o[k],
    asc = (a, b) => (a > b) - (a < b),
    desc = swap(asc),
    transpose = array => array.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), []),
    take = pre => fn => (x, y) => fn(pre(x), pre(y)),
    sortBy = fn => array => array.sort(fn),
    pipe = (...functions) => input => functions.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), input),
    pipeline = pipe(
        transpose,
        sortBy(take(prop(1))(desc)),
        transpose
    );
 

let labels = ["John", "Sophie", "Hannah", "Emilia"],
    data = [10, 40, 24, 25];
    
    
[labels, data] = pipeline([labels, data]);

console.log(...labels);
console.log(...data);
```

Comment: amazing, too bad `|>` is not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can first merge both the arrays into one like

```
[
 {label: ..., rank: ...},
 {label: ..., rank: ...},
 {label: ..., rank: ...},
]
```

Then sort the above array using the `rank` property

And finally, map the array to extract either the `label` or `rank` properties

```js
const labels = ["John", "Sophie", "Hannah", "Emilia"]

const ranks = [10, 40, 24, 25];

// Merge them both to a single array
const labelRankList = labels.map((label, i) => ({
  label,
  rank: ranks[i]
}));

const sortedList = labelRankList
  .sort((a, b) => b.rank - a.rank) // Sort by rank

console.log("Labels : ", sortedList.map(x => x.label));
console.log("Data : ", sortedList.map(x => x.rank));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [40, 25, 24, 10];
let labels = ["Sophie", "Emilia", "Hannah", "John"];

const res = data.map((n, i) => [labels[i], n])
           .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
           .map(a => a[0])


console.log(res); // [ 'John', 'Hannah', 'Emilia', 'Sophie' ];
```

Comment: `data.map((n, i) => ({ [labels[i]]: n }))` is a bit of a waste. Making each into a key-value pair only to use `Object.values()` on each and then `Object.keys`. Those can be skipped if you initially map to just arrays of pairs: `data.map((n, i) => [labels[i], n])`

Comment: Yea, I thought about it after. I guess I need to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option that doesn't zip the related arrays, instead it creates an index array, sorts it by the relevant source array and then orders all the passed arrays by the sorted indexes.

```js
const sortBySharedIndex = (...arrs) => {
  const index = arrs[0].map((_, i) => i)
  index.sort((a, b) => arrs[0][b] - arrs[0][a]);

  return arrs.map(arr => index.map(i => arr[i]));
}

let data = [10, 40, 24, 25];
let labels = ["John", "Sophie", "Hannah", "Emilia"];

let [sortedData, sortedLabels] = sortBySharedIndex(data, labels);

console.log(...sortedData)
console.log(...sortedLabels)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `.map()` to merge the arrays into an array of arrays (2D array)

   ```
   [[10, 'John'], [40, 'Sophie'], ...]
   ```
2. Then `.sort()` by each sub-array's first element

   ```
   arrArr[0][0] = 10, arrArr[1][0] = 40
   ```
3. Then use a `for...of` loop to `.push()` each element of each sub-array into a new array.

***Details are commented in demo below***

```js
let labels = ["John", "Sophie", "Hannah", "Emilia"];

let data = [10, 40, 24, 25];

// map() into an array of arrays
// ex. [[10, 'John'], [40, 'Sophie'],...]
let twoDArr = data.map((num, idx) => [num, labels[idx]]);

// sort() by the first element of each sub-array.
// ex. twoDArr[0][0] = 10, twoDarr[1][0] = 40
let sorted = twoDArr.sort((a, b) => b[0] - a[0]);

/* 
for each sub-array of sorted 2D array 
push sorted[i][0] into an empty array and
push sorted[i][1] into another empty array
*/

let keys = [];
let vals = [];
for (let [key, val] of sorted) {
  keys.push(key);
  vals.push(val);
}

console.log('data: '+keys);
console.log('labels: '+vals);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just map indices of `labels` to indices of `data` and sort based on values in `data` (`O(n^2logn)` complexity):

```js
const labels = ["John", "Sophie", "Hannah", "Emilia"]
const data = [10, 40, 24, 25]

const sortedLabels = labels.sort((a, b) => data[labels.indexOf(b)] - data[labels.indexOf(a)])
const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => b - a)

console.log(...sortedLabels)
console.log(...sortedData)
```

or performance version (`O(nlogn)` complexity) in case of bigger arrays:

```js
const labels = ["John", "Sophie", "Hannah", "Emilia"]
const data = [10, 40, 24, 25]
    
const merged = labels.map((e, i) => [e, data[i]])
                     .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])

const sortedLabels = merged.map(e => e[0])
const sortedData = merged.map(e => e[1])

console.log(...sortedLabels)
console.log(...sortedData)
```

Comment: This is two nested `indexOf()` calls per sort iteration, plus a second sort on the data array.

Comment: It's no a big deal. JS sort has `O(n log n)` complexity and `indexOf` has `O(n)`. Unless you have a big arrays like 1000+ elements, it shouldn't be a problem.