# javascript array multiple sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort by 2 key values ​​of object in javascript

```js
    [
   {
    "min": 8,
    "price": 2
   },
   {
    "min": 3,
    "price": 1
   },
   {
    "min": 9,
    "price": 4
   },
   {
    "min": 360,
    "price": 9
   }
  ]
```

I want to sort from descending to ascending according to min and price values.
the code i wrote

```js
const sortCardItems = cardItems
    .slice()
    .sort(
        (a, b) =>
            parseInt(a.min, 10) - parseInt(b.min, 10) &&
            parseInt(a.price, 10) - parseInt(b.price, 10),
    );
```

but it only sorts by price I want to get a result like this

e.g.

```js
[
   {
    "min": 3,
    "price": 2
   },
   {
    "min": 4,
    "price": 3
   },
   {
    "min": 5,
    "price": 4
   },
   {
    "min": 360,
    "price": 9
   }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to first get the difference between `min` and `min`s are equal, return the difference between `price`s

```js
const data = [{
    "min": 8,
    "price": 2
  },
  {
    "min": 3,
    "price": 1
  },
  {
    "min": 9,
    "price": 4
  },
  {
    "min": 360,
    "price": 9
  }
]

data.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.min - b.min || a.price - b.price
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: @Jack_Hu OP input data is different from output data. I used the input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solutions in [How to sort 2 dimensional array by column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/how-to-sort-2-dimensional-array-by-column-value), you can solve the problem by making two sort calls, such as

```
// Sort the 'min' first
cardItems= cardItems.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.min - b.min;
});


// Sort the 'price' next
cardItems= cardItems.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.price - b.price;
});
```

I didn't test the code, but you may see the idea.