# How to sort by created time when use .getFiles() in Photoshop Script?

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

```
var fileFolderArray = Folder( "~/Downloads/" ).getFiles();
```

How to sort by files created time when use getFiles function  ? thanks:)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you could sort your array manually by inspecting the file date for each item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to get the created time with .created notation. You can't use  filter or more complex JavaScript functions as Photoshop relies on earlier version of ECMAScript :(

This will work for ya:

```
myFolder = "C:\\temp";

var sorted = sort_files_by_creation_date(myFolder);
var msg ="";
for (var i = 0;  i < sorted.length; i++)
{
   msg+= sorted[i][0] + "\n";
}

alert(msg);

function sort_files_by_creation_date (afolder)
{

   var fileFolderArray = Folder(afolder).getFiles();

   var dates = [];
   for (var i = 0;  i < fileFolderArray.length; i++)
   {
      var fileCreationDate = fileFolderArray[i].created.toString();
      // var fileCreationDate = fileFolderArray[i].modified.toString();
      dates.push([fileCreationDate, fileFolderArray[i]]);
   } 

   //dates.sort()
   return dates.sort(sortFunction);  
}

function sortFunction(a, b)
{
    if (a[0] === b[0])
    {
      return 0;
    }
    else
    {
      return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Sort function taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/).